# Segmentation Fault With My Code

Tags: c

I'm quite new to C but I have no idea why i'm getting this error. I know Segmentation Fault is due to going outside of my range, but i don't know where if i am.

[This is my code](http://pastebin.com/MJfzhPL8)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int** totalMatrix(int numRows, int numCols){

    int** firstMatrix;
    int** secondMatrix;
    int** sumMatrix;
    int row, col;

    printf("Enter Matrix A\n");

    firstMatrix = (int**)malloc(numRows * sizeof(int*));
    for(row = 0; row < numRows; row++){
        firstMatrix[row] = (int*)malloc(numCols * sizeof(int));
    }

    for(row = 0; row < numRows; row++){
        for(col = 0; col < numCols; col++){
            scanf("%d", &firstMatrix[row][col]);
        }
    }
    printf("Enter Matrix B\n");

    secondMatrix = (int**)malloc(numRows * sizeof(int*));
    for(row = 0; row < numRows; row++){
        secondMatrix[row] = (int*)malloc(numCols * sizeof(int));
    }

    for(row = 0; row < numRows; row++){
        for(col = 0; col < numCols; col++){
            scanf("%d", &secondMatrix[row][col]);
        }
    }
    printf("A + B =\n");

    sumMatrix = (int**)malloc(numRows * sizeof(int*));
    for(row = 0; row < numRows; ++row){
        for(col = 0; col < numCols; ++col){
            sumMatrix[row][col] = firstMatrix[row][col] + secondMatrix[row][col];
            printf("%d ", sumMatrix[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}


void delete_matrix(int numRows, int** matrix){
    int row;
    for(row = 0 ; row < numRows; ++row){
        free(matrix[row]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}

int main(){

    int numRows, numCols;

    int** matrix;

    printf("Please Enter the number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &numRows);

    printf("Please Enter the number of cols: ");
    scanf("%d", &numCols);

    matrix = totalMatrix(numRows, numCols);

    delete_matrix(numRows, matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

[It works but crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vssrx.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should paste the relevant code into the question. Also, it may sound like a waste right now, but it's actually the perfect time to start learning how to use a debugger.

Comment: And don't tag irrelevant languages.

Comment: It's the pastebin link.

Comment: We know. Doesn't matter.

Comment: Oh, sorry, i tinkered with the built in code paste, it was just not formatting correctly.

Comment: did you try running it under a debugger

Comment: missing one `malloc` for `sumMatrix` you have for rows you don't have for cols

Comment: And `totalMatrix` return 0.  `return sumMatrix;` instead of.

Comment: Hi there @SHR. This is the comments section, which is for requesting clarification and providing constructive criticism on the question. You should take [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to find out how we do things around here. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `firstMatrix` and `secondMatrix` you correctly `malloc` the outer dimension then, in a loop, `malloc` all of the inner dimension.

**For some reason, for `sumMatrix`, you only `malloc`'d the outer dimension.** All of the pointers it stores are uninitialised yet you're dereferencing them.

*Note that when I say "correctly", I use the term loosely: this is a **lot** of unnecessary dynamic allocations! Prefer one big allocation. You can map 2D indexes over a single memory block. That would also have avoided this bug.*

Furthermore, your function always returns `0`. That's a null pointer. So when you're using it in `main` and passing it to `delete_matrix`, that's meaningless. I'd get rid of the return entirely and move the `delete_matrix` call to the bottom of `totalMatrix` (argh! inconsistent function naming!) seeing as you actually need to do it *three* times — once for each matrix.

Comment: Oh man, i completely missed that. I just fixed it; however it still persists. I didn't even know you could, i'll have to look into thanks!

Comment: @Motosuwa: Spotted another bug.

Comment: Yeah, i was tinkering with it trying to figure out why it wasn't working before i posted. I even grabbed some code that's why the name is inconsistent. I'll try to fix right now. Thanks!

Comment: It's properly working now, so thank you a ton!. But i don't quite understand when you mean add it to the bottom of totalMatrix. Do you mean pass it into the function? Wouldn't i then have to add another argument and it be more messy?

Comment: @Motosuwa: No just call `delete_matrix` from within `totalMatrix`, once for each matrix you need to delete. If you don't do that, you still need to add an extra two calls to its current location in `main`, somehow getting the matrices' pointers to that location, which would definitely be messy!

Comment: I know you've helped more than i could have ever asked for, but when you stated i was overkilling it with multiple allocations. How would i do it in one big one like with my program? I really want to understand and get better. Thanks in advance!